# Change button's content and color when clicked.

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a model at http://www.lesha.wemakesites.ru/. 
Once focused at plus icon it is replaced by a button "Follow me".
What I wanna do is to change this button to a red one saying "Unfollow" once it is clicked. It is super if someone knows how to build it reversed too so that when an "Unfollow" button is clicked, it becomes "Follow" one.

Comment: This seems to be trivial. What did you try?

Comment: Please provide the HTML/CSS/JS which you have tried so far.

Comment: .block:focus .button-2 { background: olive; }

that's what I try to do when click happens but it never works to change the background at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull in jquery in your project. This cannot be achieved with css alone.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("followed")) {
    $(this).addClass("followed btn-red");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-blue");
    $(this).html("Followed");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("btn-blue");
    $(this).removeClass("followed btn-red");
    $(this).html("Follow");
  }
});
```

```css
#btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" class="btn-blue">Follow</button>
```

Make the JS as simple as possible to understand.

Comment: how can we check .hasClass("followed") since there is no element with such a class? Don't get this condition anyway the whole thing is working...

Comment: It is checking if #btn element has a class of followed. Is that working?

Comment: It's working fine, but we don't have here an element of class followed, am I right? It has class "btn-blue" at the moment?

Comment: Initial there won't be a element with class followed but as soon as the user clicks the button the button gets a class of followed. Thats why we need to check if the btn has a class of followed.

Comment: It also works if class is changed to any word combination. Where can I read more precise about getting this class after clicking?

Comment: You can read the jquey addClass and removeClass method. It will be great if you marked this as solved so someone in future can solve as similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having two versions of the button and you can use

```
display: none;
```

for the one that is currently not in use.

If users are switching back between following you can store your state in a variable.

```
let following = true;
let btn =  document.getElementById("btn");

if (!!following) { 
  btn.style.dispaly = "none";
  following = false;
} else {
  btn.style.display = "block";
  following = false; 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to complete this task with css only?

Comment: I'd have to see your code to help you more to be honest.